# jQuery Datatable column search - how to exclude 0.00?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datatable

I am using the jQuery plugin DataTables (http://datatables.net) for pagination, search capabilities and filtering.

Here I am in need to display the **Pecent** and **Salary** rows which does not contain 0.00. I tried the below regex but not working.

'^/[+-]?((\0+.?\0*)|(.\0+))$'

Please help me to achieve this.

[demo_link](http://live.datatables.net/riqoxuja/60/edit)

**HTML Code**:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  
  // Filter out rows which do not contain a plus sign
  table.search( '^/[+-]?((\0+\.?\0*)|(\.\0+))$ ', true, false ).draw();
} );
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Pecent</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Pecent</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Non Zero row</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
            <td>System + Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>1222</td>
            <td>3.12</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zero row 1</td>
            <td>12.00</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zero row 2</td>
            <td>13.43</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you use `\0`? Did you mean `\d`, a digit?

Comment: Yes. To exclude 0.00 I used \0

Comment: But `\0` is not a `0`. Use `0` to match a `0`. `/\0/.test('0')` => `false`, `/\0/.test('\x00')` => `true`

Comment: But I want to exclude 0.00 from column 1 and 6. table.search( '^/[+-]?((\0+\.?\0*)|(\.\0+))$ ', true, false ).draw();

Comment: If you want to ONLY exclude `0.00` and that value won't show up in any other way (say, it won't be `0.000` or `+0.0`) then you can simply do `^0\.00$` - you don't need quantifiers, groups and character classes like you are trying to do. A regex that will account for variation of "zero" would be `^0(\.0+)?$` for a zero optionally followed by a dot and any number of zeroes.

Comment: It seems to work with `table.search("0.00", true, false).draw();`

Comment: A little bit unclear: "*Here I am in need to display the Pecent and Salary rows which does not contain 0.00*" - do you want to exclude all rows with salary as 0.00 or do you want to filter them out like in a search?

Comment: Maybe you want to make sure to remove rows where Column 5 has `0.00`? Try `table.column(5).search( "^(?!0+\\.0+).*", true, false).draw();`

Comment: Try `table.column(6).search( "^(?!0(?:\\.0+)?$)", true, false).draw();` I see you updated the table and it is now in Column 6.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/7sq5xjz1/10/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the rows with a "0.00" in the last cell, you could remove that rows using standard jQuery methods before creating the data table.

You can add further logic of course by changing the selector in .find(), if you excude rows with "Pecent" OR "Salary" equal "0.00" your example table would be empty, so i just check for the last cell here:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#example')
    .find("tbody td:last-child")
    .filter(function(idx, el) {
      return $(el).text() === "0.00"
    })
    .closest("tr")
    .detach();

  $('#example').DataTable();
  
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

  <link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Pecent</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Pecent</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Non Zero row</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>System + Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>1222</td>
          <td>3.12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zero row 1</td>
          <td>12.00</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zero row 2</td>
          <td>13.43</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>India</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```